# Convert String to 2D Char Array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I'm working on developing a top-down backtracking parser, but am getting stuck on importing the grammar. My instructor wants us to take a `String[]` and convert it into a `char[][]`.

For instance, the instructor would type out a grammar, `a a S b X a a S a X a S a X` on the command line, and my program is supposed to take that and put it into a 2D char arrary.

The `X`'s in the input are supposed to represent `|` in the grammar, so the resulting grammar should be

```
char[][] productions = new char[][] { {'a','a','S','b'},
                                      {'a','a','S','a'},
                                      {'a','S','a'},
                                      {'\0'} };
```

Where `\0` represents the empty string. The following code I have produces `char[4][]` but I'm unsure of how I can make arrays for each separate production.

```
    char[][] prod; int prodCount = 0, numProds = 0;
    String[] input = new String[] {"a","a","S","b","X","a","a","S","a","X",
                                    "a","S","a","X"};

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if(input[i] == "X") 
            prodCount++;
    }

    prod = new char[prodCount][];

    for(int i = 0; i < prod.length; i++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < input.length; k++) {
            if(input[k] == "X") {
                prod[i] = new char[numProds];
                numProds = 0; break;
            } else
                numProds++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < prod.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
            if(input[j] == "X") break;
            prod[i][j] = input[j].charAt(0);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: 
I've worked out how to convert the grammar, but am stuck on how I can involve `\0` in my 2D array.

```
    char[][] prod; int prodCount = 0, numProds = 0;
    String[] input = new String[] {"a","a","S","b","X",
                                   "a","a","S","a","X",
                                   "a","S","a","X"};

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if(input[i] == "X") 
            prodCount++;
    }

    prod = new char[prodCount][];

    int current = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if(input[i] == "X") {
            prod[current] = new char[numProds];
            current++; numProds = 0;
        } else
            numProds++;
    }

    int currentTerminal = 0; current = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if(input[i] == "X") {
            currentTerminal = 0;
            current++;
        }
        else {
            prod[current][currentTerminal] = input[i].charAt(0);
            currentTerminal++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some simple code that does what you need:

```
    String grammar = "aaSbXaaSaXaSaX";
    String[] components = grammar.split("X");
    char[][] chars = new char[components.length + 1][];
    for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
        String component = components[i];
        chars[i] = component.toCharArray();
    }
    chars[components.length] = new char[] { '\0' };
```

Comment: I didn't even think about `split()` :P

Comment: However, the grammar that I will use will be imported as a `String[]` so I won't be able to use `split()` on it.